# Api Rest con SpringFramework no me funcionar 'obtene todos los usuarios'

Tags: api, spring, jpa

Estoy haciendo una API REST en **spring framework** y he empezado con **usuarios**.

Voy a dejar los ficheros que estan implicados por si localizais algun error que no alcanzo a ver, porque realmente no entiendo porque no funciona:

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_tienda?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

server.port=8080
```

**Entity**

```
package com.crn.tienda.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

/**
 * Cliente
 */
@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "apellidos")
    private String apellidos;

    @Column(name = "usuario")
    private String usuario;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "passsword")
    private String passsword;

    @Column(name = "fecha_registro")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createAt;

    /**
     * @return Long return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the apellidos
     */
    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * @param apellidos the apellidos to set
     */
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the usuario
     */
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @param usuario the usuario to set
     */
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the passsword
     */
    public String getPasssword() {
        return passsword;
    }

    /**
     * @param passsword the passsword to set
     */
    public void setPasssword(String passsword) {
        this.passsword = passsword;
    }

    /**
     * @return Date return the createAt
     */
    public Date getCreateAt() {
        return createAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param createAt the createAt to set
     */
    public void setCreateAt(Date createAt) {
        this.createAt = createAt;
    }

}
```

**DAO**

```
    package com.crn.tienda.dao;

    import com.crn.tienda.entity.Usuario;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

    /**
     * IUsuarioDao
     */
    public interface IUsuarioDao extends CrudRepository<Usuario,Long> {

        @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.email = ?1 and u.password = ?2")
        Usuario findByEmailandPassword(String email, String password);

        @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.usuario = ?1 and u.password = ?2")
        Usuario findByUserandPassword(String usuario, String password);

    }
```

**Services (IUsuarioService)**

```
package com.crn.tienda.services;

import java.util.List;

import com.crn.tienda.entity.Usuario;

/**
 * IUsuarioService
 */
public interface IUsuarioService {

    public List<Usuario> findAll();

}
```

**Services (UsuarioServiceImpl)**

```
package com.crn.tienda.services;

import java.util.List;

import com.crn.tienda.dao.IUsuarioDao;
import com.crn.tienda.entity.Usuario;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * UsuarioServiceImpl
 */
@Service
public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements IUsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private IUsuarioDao usuarioDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Usuario> findAll() {
        return (List<Usuario>) usuarioDao.findAll();
    }

}
```

**Controllers**

```
package com.crn.tienda.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import com.crn.tienda.entity.Usuario;
import com.crn.tienda.services.IUsuarioService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * UsuarioRestController
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UsuarioRestController {

    @Autowired
    private IUsuarioService usuarioService;

    @GetMapping("/usuarios")
    public List<Usuario> index() {
        return usuarioService.findAll();
    }


}
```

Entonces cuando accedo a mi url (`http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios`) me da un error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon May 27 23:08:36 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Deberia de mandarme un JSON de todos los **usuarios** de la base de datos.

MI DER es el siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento no he logrado encontrar donde esta el error.
A ver si me podeis echar una mano. Mil gracias.

El **Log** es el siguiente:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _

 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \

( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \

 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )

  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /

 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)



2019-05-27 23:21:02.356  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] com.crn.tienda.demo.DemoApplication      : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-REPNVGL with PID 9260 (C:\Users\Josel\Desktop\TIENDA-SPRING-ANGULAR\BACKEND\tienda\demo\target\classes started by Josel in C:\Users\Josel\Desktop\TIENDA-SPRING-ANGULAR\BACKEND\tienda\demo)

2019-05-27 23:21:02.362  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] com.crn.tienda.demo.DemoApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2019-05-27 23:21:02.432  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable

2019-05-27 23:21:02.432  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'

2019-05-27 23:21:03.511  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.

2019-05-27 23:21:03.542  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 17ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.

2019-05-27 23:21:04.005  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8fde8269] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2019-05-27 23:21:04.470  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

2019-05-27 23:21:04.499  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2019-05-27 23:21:04.499  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]

2019-05-27 23:21:04.634  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2019-05-27 23:21:04.634  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2202 ms

2019-05-27 23:21:04.894  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2019-05-27 23:21:05.077  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

2019-05-27 23:21:05.126  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [

    name: default

    ...]

2019-05-27 23:21:05.228  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}

2019-05-27 23:21:05.230  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

2019-05-27 23:21:05.405  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}

2019-05-27 23:21:05.564  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect

2019-05-27 23:21:05.838  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

2019-05-27 23:21:05.859  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729

2019-05-27 23:21:06.134  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

2019-05-27 23:21:06.195  WARN 9260 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning

2019-05-27 23:21:06.506  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''

2019-05-27 23:21:06.510  INFO 9260 --- [  restartedMain] com.crn.tienda.demo.DemoApplication      : Started DemoApplication in 4.594 seconds (JVM running for 5.149)
```

Comment: y que error te da?

Comment: esta puesto en la pregunta fijate encima de la image del DER.

Comment: Puede que sea tema de los paquetes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819277/issue-with-spring-there-was-an-unexpected-error-type-not-found-status-404

Comment: eso he estado probando pero por ejemplo si el main esta en `loquesea.main` mis paquetes de **controllers,entities,etc..**  deben de ser `loquesea.main.controllers......` pero no me funciona tampoco. Tambien lo he probado poniendo asi como en le ejemplo (con los puntos) o creandolo directamente dentro del directorio, pero en ambas no funcionan, de hecho ni compilan.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a tu pregunta una captura donde se vea la estructura de paquetes, y que se vea dónde está el main y dónde los  controladores? ¿Y puedes añadir también el código de la clase main con las anotaciones que tengas en ella?